# Correct criterion for the difference between two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us denote $V = sp(v_1,...,v_k)$ where $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I have an algorithm that approximates the vector $v_i$ by some $v'_i$. Denote $V' = sp(v'_1,...,v'_k)$. I am interested in the "difference" between $V$ and $V'$, and not the individual vectors. What would be right criterion for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You could lose or gain in dimension but any subtler difference won’t occur since you’re taking the span (all that matters is how many linearly independent vectors there are in each set V and V’)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use ranks.

Let $A$ be the matrix with the coordinates of a basis of $V$.

Let $B$ be $A$ augmented with the coordinates of a basis of $V'$.

The difference $f(V,V')=\text{rank}(B) - \text{rank}(A)$ measures how far $V'$ is from $V$.

If you want a symmetric function, use $f(V,V')+f(V',V)$.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\dim (V)$ and $\operatorname{rank} (B)=\dim(V+V')$ so your symmetric function is equal to $2\dim(V+V')-\dim(V)-\dim(V')$.